# Replace href link with a JS function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

In my react electron app, that it is working with an API, I receive JSON values to display data into the components. So for example I have a `Features` component:

```
const Features = () => {
  const { title } = useSelector(({ titles }) => titles);
  let string = title.features;
  // the string can contain some html tags. Example bellow:
  // sting = 'This is a string containing a href to <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>';

  string = string.replace(/href="(.*?)"/g, function() {
    return `onClick="${() => shell.openExternal('www.google.com')}"`;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Heading>Features</Heading>
      <Text content={parsedHTML} />
    </>
  );
};
```

What I want is to replace the `href` attribute with `onClick` and assign Electron's `shell.openExternal()` function.

The `string.replace()` callback function does that, but when I click on the `<a>` element, the app throws next error:

> error: uncaughtException: Expected `onClick` listener to be a
> function, instead got a value of `string` type.

**UPDATE**

Also tried this logic and the same error occurs:

```
  global.openInBrowser = openInBrowser; // openInBrowser is basically a function that calls shell.openExternal(url)

  const re = new RegExp('<a([^>]* )href="([^"]+)"', 'g');
  string = string.replace(re, '<a$1href="#" onClick="openInBrowser(\'$2\')"');
```

Here's a link to [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-cherry-fmtvq?file=/src/App.js) rep.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: try just `onClick="shell.openExternal('www.google.com')"`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I already tried, same error appears

Comment: That's because you pass a string to onClick. Just remove the quotes, like this: 'onClick={shell.openExternal('www.google.com')}'

Comment: @k-wasilewski yes, I tried this as well, also the same error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` not being set on the React element is actually expected behavior.

Because there's an XSS security risk when evaling the `onclick` string. The recommended solution is to use the `replace` option in  `html-react-parser`.

you can also use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which involves security risk.

**[Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-butterfly-zbnbz?file=/src/App.js)**

```
export default function App() {
  let string =
    'This is a string containing html link to <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>';

  const re = new RegExp('<a([^>]* )href="([^"]+)"', "g");
  let replaced = string.replace(re, "<a onclick=\"alert('$2')\"");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: replaced}}></p>
      <p>{parse(string, {
        replace: domNode => {
          if (domNode.name === 'a') {
            let href = domNode.attribs.href
            domNode.attribs.onClick = () => { alert(href) }
            delete domNode.attribs.href
          }
        }
      })}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're right, this is the answer I expected to hear, but already figured it out my self. Maybe I should've mentioned in the code description above, that I already use this library to parse the html.

Comment: The replace method, from `html-react-parser` did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on specifics of electron, but passing a `(function(){functionName()})()` would not work in html if there is no functionName variable available on window scope. Being there is a global environment in electron this might answer your question:

```
const Features = () => {
  const { title } = useSelector(({ titles }) => titles);
  let string = title.features;
  // the string can contain some html tags. Example bellow:
  // sting = 'This is a string containing a href to <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>';
  
  function runOpen(href){
      shell.openExternal(href)
  }      

  global.runOpen = runOpen;

  string = string.replace(/href="(.*?)"/g, function() {
    return `onClick="runOpen(${'www.google.com'})"`;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Heading>Features</Heading>
      <Text content={parsedHTML} />
    </>
  );
};
```

if it doesnt you can use something like `onclick="console.log(this)"` to find out what is the scope the onclick runs in and futher assign your runOpen variable there.

Comment: I tried multiple times and is the same, first React throws a Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type. then the error.

Comment: When adding `console.log()` inside `onClick` it doesn't reach this code because of the error React is throwing

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you are using something like `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={parsedHTML} />` since you are parsing html as string. But you could turn a `string` variable to `objectParams` instead and pass along {onClick: () => shell.openExternal(href)}, and set param value where you invoke the element. Although I am quite curious how do you apply you element's string to your content if not for dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned in the code description above, that I already use `html-react-parser` library to parse the html. Sorry for that

Comment: Haven't heard of this library, will check it out. tnx.